# Build service could not create build operation

Tags: xcode

My project worked fine, but after I changed to the last commit Xcode is showing me the strange error message:

```
Build service could not create build operation: unknown error while handling message: unknownSession
```

It indexes the files for a few hours and after that is finished the build fails also because of this strange bug.

Comment: My project was working in Xcode 13.2.1 and with the update to Xcode 13.3, I get this same problem. On a clean! Not even a build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For myself, I solved it by deleting the code from my pc completely and fetching it from my GitHub repository again. When I build now it works. The code has not changed but I guess Xcode has some strange bugs.

Answer (score 7):

I got this same error and closing Xcode, deleting derived data, and trying again fixed the issue for me.

I did not have to deleting the code or anything like that as mentioned in the other answer. Just deleting derived data.

Comment: This is just a temporary fix. after some time it starts appearing again forcing you to clear derived data folder again which leads to longer build times for first time.

Answer (score -3):

Close this error project or workspace and open again, then build build success